# kirby .htaceess and GET variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, kirby

I'm currently building a gallery in [Kirby](http://getkirby.com/) and have an album page that effectively has two modes: 1) Gallery listing, showing all items. 2) Single Image. I'm passing in a `GET` variable like so:

```
/gallery/album-name?p=03.jpg
```

What I really want is a URL like this:

```
/gallery/album-name/03.jpg
```

Kirby already does some url rewriting in its default `.htaccess` file, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

Which re-writes the urls from this `/index.php/gallery/album-name?p=03.jpg` removing the `index.php` part.

Now, I did think I could simply have it rewrite any URL that has a get variable like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

But that didn't seem to work.

My question is this: Can this be done? And if so, will the `GET` variable still be available to my script?

Many thanks!

---

My current full re-write rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#//www. vs //
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# block text files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ error [R=301,L]

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) error [R=301,L]

# block all files in the kirby folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^kirby/(.*) error [R=301,L]

# make panel links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]

# make gallery links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.jpg)?$ index.php?p=$2 [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

This works for everything, but I get a 404 on (for example) this url: `/gallery/my-gallery-name/01.jpg`

Comment: I'd suggest you to not change the rewrite rules but instead use the params functionality coming with kirby: http://getkirby.com/blog/the-mighty-mighty-uri-object

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work

```
RewriteRule ^our-wedding/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Now you can access it via

```
/gallery/our-wedding/03.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, but the /our-wedding/ part of the `URL` is already rewritten by the .htaccess. The base URL looks like this: `mysite.com/index.php/gallery/our-wedding/?p=01.jpg`. There are also many galleries.

Comment: I imagine with this method I'd have to add a rule every time I add a gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Your [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) has a [regular expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) with two parts

```
^(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$
  |    |
  $1   $2
```

`$1` is the gallery part and `$2` is the optional picture part.
You can use only one of those parts or both, whatever you need. If you want to use only the picture part, you must use `$2` in your rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?p=$2 [L]
```

Although, your image part regular expression does *not* match `03.jpg`. If you want to match that, you must include a dot `.` in the character class `[...]` or add an extension to it

```
[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I still can't get the thing to work. I've matched using `^gallery` as using `^(.*)` meant my other links around the site stopped working (like `/about`, etc)... I've pasted my full rewrite rules in the question.

Comment: @JonRoobottom This should work. Do you have `index.php` in the root directory?

Comment: Yes. I don't know if [Kirby](http://getkirby.com) is doing any other funky stuff. I posted my full .htacccesss rewrite rules above, maybe there's some conflict there? Thanks!

Comment: @JonRoobottom I have already seen your .htaccess. I tested it in my environment and it works here. Can you do some `echo $_GET['p']` in your script, to see, if it is called? Maybe the 404 comes from script and not from the .htaccess. Can you see the rewrite log, if there's something going wrong?

Comment: I did a var dump of `GET` vars on my error page, but none were being passed to the page. I don't have a physical directory called `gallery` everything runs through the `index.php` file. The combination of the .htaccess and Kirby doing some internal redirection is causing this not to work.

Comment: @JonRoobottom So, the `index.php` seems to be called. This is good, because then the rewrite rules work. Just a nitpick `GET` vs `_GET`. You can also try `phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES);`. This shows the `_GET` and all other variables available.